# How to replace blocks of text in notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

How to replace blocks of text in notepad++

This questions is so stupid it’s ridiculous…but I couldn’t find any easy answer on Google…so here it is:

I have a list:

```
1
2
3
a
b
c
```

How can I replace

```
1
2
3
```

With:

```
4
5
6
```

So the result is:

```
4
5
6
a
b
c
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you a are looking for an answer on **how to replace a text extending over several lines** (in other words contains (os-specific) line break character or characters).

Well there is the problem with the os-specific line break characters: Unix, Windows and Mac use different characters for line breaks. If you Know your specific line break character skip to the last paragraph.

Do a regular expression find/replace like this:

- Open Replace Dialog
- **Find What:** `1(\R)2(\R)3(\R)`
- **Replace With:** `4\15\16\1`
- Check **regular expression**
- Click Replace or Replace All

Here we use a regular expression that matches the os-specific line break character with `\R` and stores them into the placeholders `\1`, `\2` and `\3` (it is safe to assume each line break character is the same, so we only use `\1` three times in the replace part).

If you know what your os-specific line break character is, you can use that one directly:

- for Linux/Unix you would search for `1\n2\n3\n` and replace with `4\n5\n6\n`
- for Windows you would search for `1\r\n2\r\n3\r\n` and replace with `4\r\n5\r\n6\r\n`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everybody for trying, but the answer is simple yet a little convoluted...

This only works in Notepad++ 32 bit, not 64 bit...

You need the plugin manager and then to install tool bucket extension, the press:

```
     alt+shift+s
```

The the window will pop up for multiple find and replace lines